# How to get response from callback every time api called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have search function that receive string from client, so once loop process is done sending matching `results` to client using callback. With below code two issues

1-first time when i have search string it sends the response `results` but when

2- second if i search different string it sends empty array of `results`

3- if i search first string again i get the response

Any idea what is implemented wrong in below code.

app.js

```
app.get('/serverSearch', function (req, res) {
    var searchTxt = req.query.searchTxt;
    dirDirectory.readDirectory(function(logFiles){
        // res.json(logFiles);
        if(logFiles){
            searchFileService.readFile(searchTxt,logFiles,function(lines,err){
                        console.log('Logs',lines);
                          if (err)
                           return res.send();
                           res.json(lines);
                    })

        }
    });

    console.log('Search text', searchTxt);
});
```

searchService.js

```
var results = [];
var searchStr;
function readFile(str, logFiles, callback) {
    searchStr = str;
    // loop through each file
    async.eachSeries(logFiles, function (logfile, done) {
        // read file
        fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            var lines = data.split('\n'); // get the lines
            lines.forEach(function(line) { // for each line in lines
                if (line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) { // if the line contain the searchSt
                    results.push(line);
                }
            });
            // when you are done reading the file
            done();
        });

    // wrong: }), function (err) {
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error', err);
        }
        console.log('all done: ', results);

        // wrong: results.map(result, function (result){
        results.map(function (result){
            console.log(result);
        });

        // send back results
        callback(results);
        results = [];
    });
}
```

Comment: I couldn't see where `results` variable is defined

Comment: i added to question thats declared as global variable

Comment: So comes my second question: Why do you need `results` to be declared as a global variable?

Comment: If you define `results` as a global variable then you risk 2 simultaneous search results mixing. If you define it in `readFile` function's scope then we'll know that this is not the issue

Comment: Even i change `results` as a local variable problem is same